# why is the range of the function $\sqrt x$ the set of numbers $\geq 0$

Tags: functions

I have tried looking for an explanation why the range of $$\sqrt x$$ is the set of non-negative real numbers, but I have found none.

I think the range should include negative real numbers because $$\sqrt 4= \pm 2 \ .$$

So why is it so?

Comment: $\sqrt{4}=2$, NOT $\pm 2$. It is ONLY the positive square root.

Comment: Why the positive square root only?

Comment: Because otherwise it is not a function from a subset of the reals to the reals

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $\sqrt4$ were taken to $2$ and to $-2$, then $\sqrt x$ would not be a function, which is a relation that associates an input to a single output

Comment: There is a difference between $\sqrt{4}$ and the solutions of $x^{2} = 4$. Although it looks like the same thing, we understand by $\sqrt{4}$ only $2$ and not $+-2$.

Comment: Thanks, i now get it there is no such thing as one to many function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A function is a relation from a domain to a codomain such that every element of the domain is related to exactly one element of the codomain.

Comment: Lol why the downvote ? That doesn't seem like constructive criticism.

Answer (score 4):

Let me tell you first that
$\sqrt4$ is always $2$ not $\pm \,2$. Square root of a positive no. Is always positive.

Like $\sqrt{16}$ is just $4$, not $\pm \, 4$.

And we develop misconception from here. 
In school we are taught to solve ques like
$$x^2 = 4$$
Then we take root both side,

$$x = \sqrt4$$
And then we write, $x = \pm\,2$
Although the above solution is correct but the way it is done is wrong.

The right method is
$$x^2 = 4$$
Taking root both side 
$$\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt4,$$
$$|\,X\,| = 2$$
Then we come to result that
$x= \pm\,2$
So in your $f(x) : \sqrt x$ , 
 x can't take negative values
And if it takes positive values then answer will be surely a positive number.

I hope you cleared your misconception today that $\sqrt4$ is just $2$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please [edit] you answer and improve it? In particular it will be more readable if you use MathJax. See some tips on [answer], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already.

Answer (score 1):

There is a common confusion between solving $x^2=4$ and the square root function.

- There are two *solutions* to $x^2=4$ because there are two numbers that make the equation true, $x=2$ and $x=-2$.
- On the other hand, $\sqrt{~}$ is a *function*, which means that for any input it has at most one output.  Mathematicians have defined the square root function to return nonnegative values.

Since it has been chosen (a long time ago) that $\sqrt{~}$ on returns nonnegative values, this is why the solutions to $x^2=a$ are $\pm\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{a}$ is always nonnegative and the $\pm$ allows for the negative option.

The root (pun intended) of the problem is that the square function does not have an inverse.  In other words, there is no function that satisfies $\sqrt{x^2}=x$.  To see this: If $x=2$, then the LHS is $\sqrt{4}$, which we would want to be $2$ in this case.  If $x=-2$, then the LHS is $\sqrt{4}$, which we would want to be $-2$ in this case.  The problem is that the function applied to $4$ $\sqrt{4}$ doesn't "know" if the answer should be positive or negative (it doesn't "know" the context of the question).  $\sqrt{4}$ must be a number, so we have to pick one and stick with it.